# simple CSS style won't show.. why please?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to color a div part of my html with a background gradient that i got from a color generator but for some reason this code won't work.

I'm following css/html tutorials and i'm replicating what their doing but it's not working out for me when i make my own tweaks. See my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Let's Play</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body> 
        <div id="mainbg">this part should have a colored gradient</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

my css is..

```
<style type ="text/css">


#mainbg{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e4efc0 0%,#abbd73 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    /* background-color: rgb( 149, 206, 145); */
}
</style>
```

not even a plain background is showing up.. thanks in advance

Comment: What browser you're using to test? I'm running Chrome and I see the gradient with no problems (http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/BUuav/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `<style type ="text/css">` and `</style>` tags from your CSS file leaving you with:

```
#mainbg{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e4efc0 0%,#abbd73 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    /* background-color: rgb( 149, 206, 145); */
}
```

Comment: But if that's a style block from your HTML file, leave those tags in.  +1

Comment: thanks it worked! The reason I put them in there is bkz this tutorial i was following had them... what do they mean?

Comment: You would use those tags if you were defining CSS directly in the HTML file

Answer (score 0):

You say that your css is:

```
<style type ="text/css">...
```

I think the style tag is causing the issue as I don't see anything wrong with your css code.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://davidwalsh.name/css-gradients) seems to cover just about everything with regards to `css3` gradients.

You will definitely want to add:

- -moz filter
- -ms-filter
- -ms-
- -o-
- etc.